# "delivered something as broken"

Tags: adverbs

> My phone was delivered **as** broken

Is the use of **as** correct in this sentence? I mean that they delivered broken phone to me. I just wonder if **as** can be used in this way generally.

Answer (score 2):

> My phone was delivered as broken.

When used as a conjunction "as" links the two verbs meaning that they are connected. In this case, I don't think that is your intention as the person delivering your phone is unlikely to know that it was broken. It may have been delivered in a broken state, but it was not delivered *on the basis* or on an *understanding* that it was broken. You would not have known it was broken until you opened the packaging.

"As" might be used in similar sentences though. For example, if you went to a store and intentionally bought something damaged (like an imperfect garment, sold at a discount), you might say:

> The jacket was sold as damaged.

This is correct because the store knew it was damaged, you knew it was damaged, and it was sold on that basis so there is a link between it being sold and damaged.

If you want to say that your phone was damaged during the delivery, you could say:

> My phone was broken *in* delivery.

You may not know that for certain though, and if you are simply trying to say that your phone arrived in a broken state, say:

> My phone was delivered broken.